# Generate number set with conditions using n numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, combinatorics, open-ended-function

Generate \$T=\{T_1,...,T_x\}\$, the minimum number of \$k\$-length subsets of \$\{1,...,n\}\$ such that every \$v\$-length subset of \$\{1,...,n\}\$ is a subset of some set in \$T\$

1. Here, \$n > k > v\$ and \$v \ge 2\$
2. Any number can appear only once in 1 set
3. Order of numbers is not important

Answer with code & explanation

### Test Cases

\$(n,k,v) \to output \$

```
(4, 3, 2)  ->  {1  2  3}    
               {1  2  4}
               {1  3  4}
                    

(10, 6, 3) ->  {1  2  3  4  5  7}
               {2  3  4  5  6  8}
               {3  4  5  6  7  9}
               {4  5  6  7  8 10}
               {1  5  6  7  8  9}
               {2  6  7  8  9 10}
               {1  3  7  8  9 10}
               {1  2  4  8  9 10}
               {1  2  3  5  9 10}
               {1  2  3  4  6 10}
```

Comment: You say v>2, but one of your test cases has v=2. Did you mean v≥2?

Comment: I think these are called *covering designs*.

Comment: May we use \$\{0,\dots,n-1\}\$ instead?

Comment: @xnor corrected v

Comment: @Arnauld if that helps, that's fine

Comment: Is it [tag:open-ended-function]? I can think of several solutions for one input (e.g. one will be swapping `1` to `2` in third set of the first test case). If that's correct, how to handle those multiple solutions? Are we allowed to output all/any of them or a specific one?

Comment: @pajonk if you think about it , 1 completes the requirement in set 1 & 2 .So is the case with 2. So yes any one of those could have been used for 3rd set. As mentioned all needed is to meet the condition atleast once ,so any 1 set of output is the solution

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œcŒPṚœc€⁵ẎQLƲÞṪ
```

A full program that accepts alphabet size (n), block size (k), and subset size (v) and prints a minimum covering design.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//xZNjxZJQ4bmaxZNj4oKs4oG14bqOUUzGssOe4bmq////NP8z/zI)**

#### How?

Naive brute-force, and about as inefficient as possible!

```
œcŒPṚœc€⁵ẎQLƲÞṪ - Main Link: n, k
œc              - k-combinations of [1..n] without repeats
  ŒP            - powerset
    Ṛ           - reverse (to be from longest to shortest)
             Þ  - (stable) sort (these proposed solutions) by:
            Ʋ   -   last four links as a monad:
        ⁵       -     with right argument = third program argument (v)
       €        -       for each k-tuple in the proposed solution:
     œc         -         v-combinations of the k-tuple
         Ẏ      -     tighten to a list of the covered v-tuples
          Q     -     deduplicate
           L    -     length -> number of distinct v-tuples covered
              Ṫ - tail -> i.e. (one of) the shortest valid proposed solution(s)
                - implicit print
```

---

##### Aside:

A greedy method of adding the lexicographically first unused block that covers the most so far uncovered subsets gets an optimal covering design *sometimes* and a fairly good alternative (slightly larger number of blocks) other times. Using other orderings (than lexicographic) with the same selection criteria will find optimal coving designs *sometimes* too. See [New Constructions for Covering Designs
(Daniel M. Gordon, Greg Kuperberg, Oren Patashnik)](https://www.dmgordon.org/papers/cover.pdf)

This [Python code](https://tio.run/##lVTLjpswFN3zFVeq1DGqO0o61Swi0VXX7QdMIsTDBGuMjWyTzBTx7enFJhBComm9MH7cc@65D1O/21LJp9Op0KqCTAnBMsuVNMCrWmkLv3XONMt/8swGzoZbpq1SYrTIVJVymThUEAQ5K2DPbJypA9MkEXWZpLg1/A@jkAqVvQ5r06RmuAg3AeA4G0MEOpF7RtYUZgTwBdahM22k42d57GkMYvBDLsWMzue@PMEnZBZeD0YiQbA3nqm9TuqSZ4kA1cdN4chtCbZkcHaD63dwvgcdjUERnie26iwnHuShrIsMEofpB3EIutR8Pr8UHI6wQmmv2Unm5m7AU6IHtJ@dKtT0snPbY8kFW@ZyM/pLmbE@OAT9UpKNN1XyxqtE@DhxbmRfttVSKYXrSqH0j9L2iF1WGRJOSvoh2TFelv365PMyoBkLL7DYktwgC@HHrbjmIu4Hf491AZ9l1X1nJh8l58Xd7BB7w9vI5M4fk7pmMieTx0nN8gl9jf7B98i0G5lyJv4fqJlttByeUhD0/SIpYLscKKjauvxiRvf4/rBhCPlO4YnCN5xDCmS9ovDsTtarfo9rb/AcDk2jmWlEX5bpZzTw@xTUmktLigcZtbLDi6h9xc8hag/dZitbD@@2kngRUduX15@G3bXEqJ3vu3ArH8LgdPoL) does this with the lexicographic ordering - it gets a different, optimal solution for `n=10 k=6 v=3` (also 10 blocks), but a non-optimal one for (for example) `n=6 k=4 v=3` (one too many blocks).

Comment: I tried running  `(10, 6, 3)` but it timed out

Comment: @2FaceMan it will, you'll have to run it on your own computer and wait several minutes (if not hours) probably

Comment: @2FaceMan yep, too inefficient for that - it would construct a list of all \$2^{210}\$ collections of 6-tuples and then do the sort by number of 3-tuples covered. That will need quite a bit longer than 60 seconds!

Comment: @Steffan you'll need an absolute tonne of memory too! (and I doubt it'd be hours even :p)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Is there a way , getting count of set is less time consuming ?  I can try validate against minimum count

Comment: @2FaceMan the code above constructs the covering design by analysing all possible sets of the k-sets, so it can't be tweaked to output the solution's cardinality faster. I could be wrong, but I think the problem itself is NP-complete so without a significant leap, we must find a valid result before we can provide the cardinality.

Comment: @2FaceMan - https://www.dmgordon.org/papers/cover.pdf

Comment: @JonathanAllan I have seen that & then formed question . I was just trying see if I can match count of o/p from your code against his repository . As you explained count wont change much , I will leave it to that.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
ɾḋṗṘµ⁰vḋÞfUL;t
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuG4i+G5l+G5mMK14oGwduG4i8OeZlVMO3QiLCIiLCI0XG4zXG4yIl0=)

Basically a port of Jelly, aka extremely slow.

Explanation coming soon.

Comment: *"Explanation coming soon."*

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES10), 188 bytes

Another brute-force solution that is unlikely to solve the second test case before the heat death of the universe.

Results are 0-indexed.

```javascript
(n,k,v)=>(g=(v,i=n,a=[])=>i--?g(v,i,a).concat(g(v-1,i,[i,...a])):v?[]:[a],F=s=>s.find(c=>g(v).every(b=>c.some(a=>b.every(v=>a.includes(v)))))||F(s.flatMap(a=>g(k).map(b=>[...a,b]))))([[]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BasMwDIZfpUcJFMG6nQpyb731CYwPiuMEr6kd6sww6LtnNkwn6ePj1/@tVYt/xW0fUp7CMcsBiR5UUQwsApWiJFKxroE4DNelI1Jkn5PXHdo9fDRiIzGzOsRLvVp3seroJkVM4TmmCbyYpiKHGl6/MIrxXPIzgIoZ/2EVoxyTX3@mUJrb5/2@QUtYdb/r1uUFHsjPtrcI2z/S6LoI1jqHR2tV8hp4zQvM8EWnTzqdEY8/)

### Commented

#### Helper function

\$g\$ is a helper function that, given \$v\$, returns the list of all subsets of \$[0\dots n-1]\$ of length \$v\$. (Note that it is meant to be defined in the scope of the main function so that \$n\$ is known.)

```javascript
g = (                   // g is a recursive function taking:
  v,                    //   v = expected length
  i = n,                //   i = counter, initialized to n
  a = []                //   a[] = current subset
) =>                    //
  i-- ?                 // decrement i; if it was not zero:
    g(                  //   do a recursive call where
      v, i, a           //     nothing is changed
    )                   //
    .concat(            //   append the result of
      g(                //   another recursive call where
        v - 1,          //     v is decremented
        i,              //     and
        [i, ...a]       //     i is inserted at the beginning of a[]
      )                 //
    )                   //
  :                     // else:
    v ? []              //   ignore this subset if its length is not v
      : [a]             //   otherwise, append it to the output list
```

#### Main function

```javascript
(n, k, v) => (          // f is the main function, taking n, k, v
  F =                   // F is a recursive function taking a list of
  s =>                  // lists of k-subsets
  s.find(c =>           // is there a list c[] in s[] satisfying ...
    g(v)                //   build all v-subsets
    .every(b =>         //   for each v-subset b[]:
      c.some(a =>       //     is there some k-subset a[] in c[] ...
        b.every(v =>    //       such that each value v in b[] ...
          a.includes(v) //         can be found in a[]?
        )               //       end of every()
      )                 //     end of some()
    )                   //   end of every()
  )                     // end of find()
  ||                    // if no solution was found:
    F(                  //   do a recursive call:
      s.flatMap(a =>    //     for each entry a[] in s[]:
        g(k)            //       build all k-subsets
        .map(b =>       //       for each k-subset b[]:
          [...a, b]     //         append b[] to a[]
        )               //       end of map()
      )                 //     end of flatMap()
    )                   //   end of recursive call
)([[]])                 // initial call to F with a single empty list
```

Comment: Can you please also give normal java script code , just so I can understand it better

Comment: @2FaceMan I've added a commented version.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>168</s> 165 bytes

```
from itertools import*
def f(n,k,v):
 c,r,i=combinations,range(n),0
 while i:=i+1: 
  for t in c(c(r,k),i):
   if not{*c(r,v)}-{*chain(*[c(s,v)for s in t])}:return t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY89CsJAEIX7nGLK3TiCf4UEchKxiOuuGTQzYTIqIp7ExkZbz-NtTBC7xwff4737q71YLfx4PI-WxsvPM6k0QBbVRA4dUNOKWp5tY4LkGPd48kUGARWpDNJsiCsj4Q614l107HGSwbmmQwQqShpNC8gAkigYEENwwSnuPdJQA0AJWOyaD_Tkb-M-1RWxy1fBdT0ZxG4Qbe1vhUY7ap9_Y9-tEptLboFznHn_o_8rXw)

### Explanation

A brute-force solution. It iterates through all possible sizes of output sets \$i=1,2,\ldots\$, then checks the condition on each, and returns the first set of sets that meets the condition.

---

-3 bytes from @Steffan for extraneous parens

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 173 bytes

```javascript
(n,k,v)=>(h=(e,...z)=>(g=(k,m=n,z=[])=>m--?[...g(k,m,z),...g(~-k,m,[m,...z])]:k?[]:[z])(v).every(i=>e.join`
`.match(i.join`,(.*,)?`))?e:h(...z,...g(k).map(x=>[...e,x])))([])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xDoMwDET3fgWjXZkMbSekwIdEkUA0QEhJEKCIMvTX0wS2e2f7zmPjm7Vd9Lzl1r1V6HgAS4Y88hIGDooYY0eCnoOhiVs6uJDRmPK8EnHYJ5sOpFP/8kRiOs8kysJUQhYiSvDIlFfLFzQvFRudtvWtZlOztQPoiwnYnbCqEStVDJAyrliDcXGGnZepUtEuERHiH6F1dnUfxT6uhw5elD0peyCGPw)

```javascript
(n,k,v)=>(
  h=(e,...z)=> // Take first
    g(v).every( // For each n choose v
      i=>e
        .join`\n` // Arrays separated by newline
                  // which won't match `.`
        .match(i.join`,(.*,)?`))?
                  // Match at least one line
        e:h(...z,...g(k).map(x=>[...e,x])) 
            // If one fail then append another and throw to end
)
([]) // Starts with nothing
```

See Arnauld's answer for explanation of `g`